# How is github's pull request related to git pull?

Tags: git, github

In https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

> Pull requests let you tell others about changes you've pushed to a repository on GitHub. Once a pull request is sent, interested parties can review the set of changes, discuss potential modifications, and even push follow-up commits if necessary.

`git pull` is to fetch a branch from a remote repository to a local repository.

Is github's pull request related to `git pull`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *pull request* on GitHub is literally a **request** to someone else that they **pull** in certain changes to their repository by running `git pull`.

They can run `git pull` (with the appropriate arguments) to pull in those changes or they can click buttons in the GitHub interface to do it.  Either way, it has basically the same effect.

The advantage of a GitHub pull request is that it makes it easy to review the changes before merging them in and encourages public discussion of the changes.

Comment: thanks. when I push to a repo in github, I will also generate a pull request. What does "generate a pull request" on giihub mean? How is it related to `git pull`?

Comment: No, pushing does not generate a pull request.  You have to click some buttons on GitHub to generate a pull request.  I don't use the phrase "generate a pull request" but I would suppose that it just means that you have entered the request into GitHub's system, which causes the people following the project to get emailed about it and causes it to get listed on GitHub's web page.  You might be confused because when you push, GitHub anticipates that you are about to make a pull request and displays a button that makes it easier for you to submit the pull request from the branch you pushed to.

Comment: Does the concept of 'pull request' in github not exist for git in general?

Comment: No, git itself just manages repositories.  There is no entry or data structure in a git repository that represents a pull request.  Git does not really help with communication between users, though it does have some features that would help you generate, email, and apply patches.

Comment: Actually there is a concept of a pull request, kind of: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull - basic idea is the same, you ask for someone to pull your changes from a specific repository.

Comment: Thanks. "A pull request on GitHub is literally a request to someone else that they pull in certain changes to their repository by running git pull."  What does `git pull` transfer my feature branch from and to? Does someone else run `git pull` to transfer my feature branch from the shared repository on GitHup to their local repository?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the name suggests some similarity, they have nothing to do with each other.

git pull is a command that will `Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch`. Typically you are on some branch on your pc and you run git pull to get all the updates that you don't have for that branch (**sync between local repository and the remote**).

#### Historical context:

When developers are using git, they do some changes in the code, and they create a commit with those changes. Those changes are called a `patch`. Git provides commands so that you can send an email to someone else (probably someone that has permissions to write on the repository) with those changes/patch, so they can review and integrate those changes. have a look at: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch

GitHub just made this process way easier with Pull Requests, that are no more than a simple "Hey guys, I made some changes, check them out, and integrate them by clicking on this green button that says `merge`"

Answer (score 0):

Not in my experience.

A pull request is basically a request for a "merge" to take place in the branch you are making the pull request to. It is a feature of GitHub, not the Git VCS.